# Statements about attributes of given function.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Let $HF(0) = \emptyset$. $HF(n+1) = P_\omega(HF(n))$, where $P_\omega(A)$ - set of all finite subsets of $A$, and $HF = \displaystyle\bigcup_{n\subset\omega}HF(n)$.

Are those statements true?

1. $HF(n-1) \subseteq HF(n) (\forall n>0).$
2. $(\forall n>0)HF(n)$ - finite.
3. $HF$ has no countable sets.

Is there any point in using math induction to prove some of the statements?

Second statement seems true because it can be proven with math induction. If $n = 1$, then it's obvious that $HF(1)$ is finite. Now suggest that $HF(n)$ is finite, then $HF(n+1)$ is a set of all finite subsets of $HF(n)$, and because $HF(n)$ is finite, then $HF(n+1)$ is finite.

I have a problem with third statement. Is it somehow a consequention of second statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two statements you can prove by induction quite easily. The third statement follows from the combination of the two:

Suppose that $x\in HF$, then there is some $n$ such that $x\in HF(n)$, therefore $x\subseteq H(n-1)$ (note that $n>0$), and therefore $x$ is a finite set.

Answer (score 1):

The third fact is even easier than Asaf makes it.

Suppose $x\in HF$, then there is some $k\in\omega$ such that $x\in HF(k)$. If $k=0$, then $HF(k)=\varnothing$ which contradicts $x\in HF(k)$. Otherwise $k=n+1$ for some $n$, and therefore $HF(k) = \mathcal P_\omega(\cdots)$ for some "$\cdots$". But that means, by definition, that every element of $HF(k)$ is finite, and therefore also $x$.

Comment: Yeah, for finite subsets it's all the same, $\mathcal P$ and $\mathcal P_\omega$. But I agree, it is slightly simpler.